# Postgresql 9.4 Subquery missing from-clause

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I have the following subquery.
In the end i want to count for every agent for all this users the controllers.
So in the substring i count the controllers for all the agent his users and
then i want to sum them up.

The substring itself is running, however i get this  error when i run the complete query

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "sub"
LINE 2: a.id as a_id, SUM(sub.c_count )  as c_count,



SELECT 
a.id as a_id, SUM(sub.c_count )  AS c_count,
(
SELECT u.id,  COUNT(c.user_id) AS c_amount
FROM users u
JOIN controllers c  ON (c.user_id = u.id)
GROUP BY
u.id
)sub
from  agents a;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because the subquery which you have aliased as `sub` returns not only multiple records, but also multiple values per record, but it appears in the `SELECT` list.  Generally, only scalars (single values) or subqueries which return a single value can appear in the `SELECT` list.  You have two options, you can either modify `sub` to return a single value, or you can try to join this subauery to the outer query.  Given that you mentioned the subquery is supposed to do some aggregation for each user or agent, my guess is that joining is the answer.  In the query below I join `sub` to the outer query on the agent ID matching the user ID from `sub`.

```
SELECT a.id AS a_id,
       COALESCE(sub.c_amount, 0) AS c_count
FROM agents a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT u.id, COUNT(c.user_id) AS c_amount
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN controllers c
        ON c.user_id = u.id
    GROUP BY u.id
) sub
    ON a.id = sub.id
```

Comment: Niiice, this is great stuff and the explanation helps me a lot. I managed to join the sub into the main query. I added the agent_id in the   subquery to use it against the `LEFT JOIN` with `a.id` (`sub.id` is the user id) But i cant group by `a.id`. Could you help me there also ?

Comment: ok i realise that is a differnt question ;) Thank s for this here ;)